# How can I Alias a folder in Apache to a single file?

Tags: apache

I want example.com/example/one?stuff=stuff and example.com/example/two?stuff=stuff to both be handled by one file on the server, /exam.py.
 I have Alias /example/ /exam.py. 
 However, going to any one of those produces a 404. What is the best way to get a single file to handle all requests to one folder, including subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AliasMatch, but you need to bake in the filesystem path:

```
AliasMatch ^/example/ /var/www/exam.py
```

Comment: when I do that it seems like my application is getting a blank URL in web.py. Any idea why or how to fix?